# Failed to login:invalid session (try restarting your game) And logs me out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My Minecraft has been doing this for a good couple weeks now. I have been completely unable to join any servers and it's really frustrating. I log into my account through the launcher and run mc. I try to join a server and it says "Failed to login:invalid session (try restarting your game)" But when I close mc and open the launcher, it makes me log in again. When I try and log in, it says my password is incorrect. I have changed it an immeasurable amount of times, and I know what it is. Once I finally get logged in again, it just does the same exact thing. I haven't been able to play Minecraft for so long and it just sucks. I have tried using different versions, changing my security questions, logging out of other accounts in my launcher, updating Java, deleting and redownloading Minecraft completely, and restarting my computer many times. I've scoured the internet looking for any resolution, but have yet to find anything to fix the issue. I'd really appreciate any help you guys can offer.

Comment: Try from a different network. Or from a different computer in the same network. Have you checked all firewalls etc.? Also, a list of links where you've already tried everything from would help, that way people don't suggest the same things again.